# checkbox Event in DataGridViewTemplate WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, checkbox, datagridview

I´m new to WPF. This is what I'm trying to do:

I have a DataGridView with one column (inspected), this column contains a checkbox that binds a boolean item, my app have to write to two Databases when I check or uncheck (SaveChangesBD function), so how do I associate an event to the checkbox that fires only when the checkbox change, but that does not fires when the datagridview loaded the first time?

And my function SaveChangesBD must be in my ViewModel class, what parameters have I pass? (I have to know the iditem)

XAML:

```
<wpftoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Static resx:Resources.inspected}">
    <wpftoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
         <DataTemplate>
             <CheckBox Name="chkIns"  
                       IsChecked="{Binding Path=Ins,
                                       UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                       CommandParameter="{Binding IsChecked,
                                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, 
                                                            Mode=TwoWay}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
   </wpftoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</wpftoolkit:DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: You don't need an event. Just call `SaveChangesBD` from `Ins` property setter.

Comment: I see your Binding a CommandParameter but not a command why is that ?

Comment: Don't you mean `SaveChangesDB` ? and like @eranotzap said, you're missing the command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have the call to the database save fire from the Ins property set. Something like:

```
public bool Ins {
  get { return _ins; }
  set { _ins = value; CallYourDBHere(); }
}
```

(Usually you'll have more code there, but for brevity it was omitted. The idea is you can do stuff from the property setter).